# Multi relation classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm ph.d. scholar in statistics. I have given task to learn classification algorithm. I successfully completed feature selection with filter and wrapper methods with weka. But it is for single table like iris or weather.

My question is that how to implement these techniques if I have to work on multiple table where all table are joined with primary and foreign keys.

If I select on table as classification then how to used other tables which are related to main table?

I need ur help to understand this question.

Comment: this is a database question and not a machine-learning/classification question right?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables like so,

**TABLES**

```
**APP_BLOG**
BLO_ID BLO_TITLE BLO_CATEGORY BLO_STATUS
1      lorem     1           1

**APP_CATEGORY**
CAT_ID CAT_NAME CAT_STATUS
1      Design   1
```

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT * FROM app_blog
LEFT JOIN app_categories ON blo_category = cat_id
```